# Pandas Plot: Index

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please help me edit the index in my plots? I'm trying to rotate the names in the plot below so that it's a bit more readable.

Is there a way to prevent the "\n" from showing in the table?

Is there a way to label the y-axis?

In:

```
index = ("Plea \n Bargain \n Felony","Plea \n Bargain \n Misdemeanor") 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
'incarceration': pd.Series((23.7,1.99), index),
'probation': pd.Series((45.0,45.9), index),
'work': pd.Series((2.4,0.3), index),
'program': pd.Series((12,0), index) 
}) 
print df2.head() 

df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Out

```
                            incarceration  probation  program  work
Plea \n Bargain \n Felony               23.70       45.0       12   2.4
Plea \n Bargain \n Misdemeanor           1.99       45.9        0   0.3

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pandas plot functions return an axis, which you can then interact with to change properties like the labels:

```
ax = df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis Label')
ax.set_xticklabels(df2.index, rotation='horizontal')
```

Result:

[image: Updated figure]

Comment: Thank you very much! --- anyway you know how to handle the "\n" funny business?

Comment: I think Marius answer with an axis solve most of your problems. You can handle "\n" problem by using below code after plotting.  `df2.index = pd.Series(df2.index).str.replace('\n', '')`.